# Did I perform the partial derivative correctly?

Tags: partial-derivative, tensor-products, tensors, tensor-rank

I have the following expression:

$\gamma^s=\sum_{s'}(X^{ss'})^{-1}m^{s'}(C-\sigma\otimes I)\cdot\varepsilon$

Where $s$ is the number of slip systems in the material and can be any integer. For this question, let's consider FCC aluminum where $s=24$. So, $\gamma^s$ is a 24x1 vector of scalars at a each $s$, $m^s$ is a 6x1x24 matrix of vectors, $C$ is a 6x6 tensor, $\sigma$ is a 6x1 vector, $\varepsilon$ is a 6x1 vector, and $X^{ss'}$ is a 24 x 24 matrix:

$X^{ss'} = h^{ss'} + C\cdot m^s\otimes m^{s'}$

I take the partial derivative of $\gamma^s$ with respect to $m^s$:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial m^s}\gamma^s=\frac{\partial}{\partial m^s}\sum_{s'}(X^{ss'})^{-1}m^{s'}(C-\sigma\otimes I)\cdot\varepsilon$

$C$, $\sigma$, and $\varepsilon$ don't depend on $m^s$, and $I$ is an 6x6 identity tensor. So I have:

$\frac{\partial\gamma^s}{\partial m^s}=\sum_{s'}\frac{\partial}{\partial m^s}(X^{ss'})^{-1}m^{s'}(C-\sigma\otimes I)\cdot\varepsilon$

Applying the product rule:

$\frac{\partial\gamma^s}{\partial m^s}=\sum_{s'}(\frac{\partial (X^{ss'})^{-1}}{\partial m^s}m^{s'} + (X^{ss'})^{-1}\frac{\partial m^{s'}}{\partial m^s})(C-\sigma\otimes I)\cdot\varepsilon$

Applying the rule of taking the derivative of an inverse matrix:

$\frac{\partial\gamma^s}{\partial m^s}=\sum_{s'}(-(X^{ss'})^{-1}\frac{\partial (h^{ss'} + C\cdot m^s\otimes m^{s'})}{\partial m^s}(X^{ss'})^{-1}m^{s'} + (X^{ss'})^{-1}\frac{\partial m^{s'}}{\partial m^s})(C-\sigma\otimes I)\cdot\varepsilon$

$h^{ss'}$ does not depend on $m^s$, and $\frac{\partial m^{s'}}{\partial m^s}$ is zero when $s' \neq s$, and is $I$ when $s' = s$. For each $s$, I have:

$\frac{\partial\gamma^s}{\partial m^s}=\sum_{s'}[-(X^{ss'})^{-1}C\cdot (\frac{\partial m^s}{\partial m^{s}}\otimes m^{s'}+m^s\otimes \frac{\partial m^{s'}}{\partial m^{s}})(X^{ss'})^{-1}m^{s'} + (X^{ss'})^{-1}\frac{\partial m^{s'}}{\partial m^s}](C-\sigma\otimes I)\cdot\varepsilon$

Writing the terms where $s' = s$ separately:

$\frac{\partial\gamma^s}{\partial m^s}=[-(X^{ss})^{-1}C\cdot (I\otimes m^{s}+m^s\otimes I)(X^{ss})^{-1}m^{s} + (X^{ss})^{-1}I+\sum_{s',s' \neq s}(-(X^{ss'})^{-1}C\cdot (I\otimes m^{s'})(X^{ss'})^{-1}m^{s'})](C-\sigma\otimes I)\cdot\varepsilon$

The problem begins here. Up to this point, I derived each step by breaking down the summation. When I check the dimensions of the final equation at a specific s and s', I get:

- The LHS partial derivative of a scalar with a 6x1 vector has a dimension of 6x6.
- The sum of tensor products $(I\otimes m^{s}+m^s\otimes I)$ gives a 6x6x6 tensor.
- Dot product with $C$ gives a 6x6x6 tensor.
- $(X^{ss})^{-1}$ is inverted beforehand as a 24 x 24 matrix, and it is simply a scalar here for a specific s and s'.
- Then multiplying by $m^s$, which is a 6x1 vector at specific s, gives a 6x6 tensor.
- $(X^{ss})^{-1}I$ is a 6x6 tensor, where $I$ is a 6x6 identity tensor.
- The summation has $C\cdot (I\otimes m^{s'})$ which is a 6x6x6 tensor.
- Dots with $m^s$ gives 6x6 tensor.
- The summation in the square bracket is a 6x6 tensor.
- Next is $(C-\sigma\otimes I)$. In the numerical code version of this equation, $I$ is treated as a vector with values [1 1 1 0 0 0], which is a 3x3 identity tensor written in Voigt notation of [11 22 33 23 13 12]. This is allowed because $\sigma$, normally a 3x3 stress tensor, is written as a 6x1 vector in Voigt notation.
- So we have a 6x6 tensor times a 6x6 tensor times a 6x1 $\varepsilon$ vector in Voigt notation. This is where I am lost since to match the LHS, it should be a 6x6 tensor, but it doesn't seem likely.

Comment: I really cannot follow your notation $\gamma^s$ has an index $s$ so it cannot be a scalar $X^{ss’}$ is a 2nd order contravariant tensor but then it has a part where a 6x6 matrix seems to contract with the Kronecker product of a vector $m^s$. Can you please define the parameters more clearly?

Comment: @TedBlack thanks for responding! Numerically speaking, gamma^s is not a scalar, but at specific s and s', gamma^s and X^ss' are both scalars. This is because S represents the number of slip systems in a material so it can be anywhere from 6 to 24. So If we say s has a range of 24, then treating gamma^s as a vector of size 24 would make it unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: I tried to remove the index s from the equations but it gets more confusing later on because we have the partial m^s' / partial m^s, where I tried to explain that for a specific s, the equation iterates through s' via the summation, and when s' is not equal to s, the partial m/partial m is zero.

Comment: ok I tried to add more context below, hopefully it is clearer.

Comment: There is no need to remove index $s$; but when you write an expression like $X^{ss'}=h^{ss'}+C \cdot m^s \otimes m^{s'}$ it is not clear what is going on; unless $C$ is a scalar I cannot see how you can add $h^{ss'}$ and $C\cdot m^s \otimes m^{s'}$. In any case, if $C$ is a tensor you need to write it down using index notation.

Comment: Another issue: you write $(C- \sigma \otimes I) \cdot \epsilon$; $C$ is a 6x6 tensor, $\sigma$ is a 6x1 vector, $I$ the 6x6 identity tensor and $\epsilon$ a 6x1 vector. $\sigma \otimes I$ generates a 6x6x6 tensor which you are supposed to subtract from $C$ which is a 6x6 tensor. How is this possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151074/discussion-between-jesse-feng-and-ted-black).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some notes on my understanding of the problem:

\begin{equation}
\dot{\gamma}^s = \pmb{f}^s \cdot \dot{\boldsymbol\varepsilon}
\end{equation}
$\dot{\gamma}^s$ is a scalar $\dot{\gamma}$ with an index ; $\pmb{f}^s$ is a vector $\pmb{f}$ with an index. So we have the dot product of two vectors which generates a scalar.

We also know that,
\begin{equation}
\dot{\gamma}^s = \sum_{s'} (X^{ss'})^{-1} \pmb{m}^{s'} 
\left(\pmb{C}-\pmb{\sigma}\otimes\pmb{I}\right)\cdot\dot{\boldsymbol\varepsilon}
\end{equation}
so we must have,
\begin{equation}
\pmb{f}^s=
\sum_{s'} (X^{ss'})^{-1} \pmb{m}^{s'} 
\left(\pmb{C}-\boldsymbol{\sigma}\otimes\pmb{I}\right)
\label{fs} \tag{I}
\end{equation}
$X$ is a scalar quantity with two indices:
\begin{equation}
X^{ss'}=h^{ss'}+\pmb{C}\cdot \pmb{m}^s \otimes \pmb{m}^{s'}
\end{equation}
If we ignore the indices $s, s'$ we have a scalar $X$  equal to the sum of another scalar $h$ and
a quantity that must also be a scalar. So,
\begin{equation}
\pmb{C} \cdot \pmb{m} \otimes \pmb{m}'
\end{equation}
must be a scalar. Since $\pmb{m}\otimes\pmb{m}'$
is a matrix I guess this is the trace of a matrix product. So the dot product of two matrices $\pmb{A},\pmb{B}$ must be,
$$
\pmb{A}\cdot\pmb{B}=\sum_i \sum_j A_{ij} B_{ji}
$$
Note that since $B_{ji}=m_j m'_i$ and $A_{ij}=C_{ij}$,
$$
\pmb{C}\cdot \pmb{m}^s \otimes \pmb{m}^{s'}
=(\pmb{m}^{s'})^T \pmb{C} \pmb{m}^s
$$
which is a quadratic form ($(-)^T$ denotes the transpose of a vector or a matrix).

The only expression left to resolve is ($\ref{fs}$);
on the l.h.s. we have a vector with an index. On the r.h.s. we have,

1. The inverse of a scalar quantity $X^{ss'}$; this is not the inverse of a tensor.
2. A vector $\pmb{m}^{s'}$.
3. The difference between two matrices
   $\pmb{C}$ and $\boldsymbol{\sigma}\otimes \pmb{I}$.

So in order for the r.h.s. to match the l.h.s.
$$
\pmb{m}^{s'} 
\left(\pmb{C}-\boldsymbol{\sigma}\otimes\pmb{I}\right)
$$
must be the product of a matrix with a vector (which is a vector; usually in a product of a matrix with a vector we write the vector on the right but lets ignore this).

If these assumptions are true then,
\begin{equation}
    d \pmb{f}^{s} =
    \sum_{s'} 
    \pmb{m}^{s'}
    \left(\pmb{C}-\boldsymbol{\sigma}\otimes\pmb{I}\right)
    d(X^{ss'})^{-1}
    +\sum_{s'}
    (X^{ss'})^{-1}
    \left(\pmb{C}-\boldsymbol{\sigma}\otimes\pmb{I}\right)
    d{\pmb{m}}^{s'}
\end{equation}
If we want to derive $\partial{\pmb{f}^s}/\partial{\pmb{m}^s}$ (so the index for $\pmb{f}$
and $\pmb{m}$ is the same)
then we have to rewrite the last equation as,
\begin{align}
    d \pmb{f}^{s} & =
    \sum_{s' \neq s} 
    \pmb{m}^{s'}
    \left(\pmb{C}-\boldsymbol{\sigma}\otimes\pmb{I}\right)
    d(X^{ss'})^{-1}
    +
    \pmb{m}^{s}
    \left(\pmb{C}-\boldsymbol{\sigma}\otimes\pmb{I}\right)
    d(X^{ss})^{-1} \nonumber \\
    & +
    (X^{ss})^{-1}
    \left(\pmb{C}-\boldsymbol{\sigma}\otimes\pmb{I}\right)
    d{\pmb{m}}^{s}    
\end{align}
We can apply the chain rule for the two differentials involving $X$:
\begin{align}
d(X^{ss'})^{-1} & = - (X^{ss'})^{-2} dX^{ss'}  \\
d(X^{ss})^{-1} & = - (X^{ss})^{-2} dX^{ss}  
\end{align}
For $dX^{ss'}$ we have,
\begin{equation}
dX^{ss'} = ( \pmb{m}^{s'})^T \pmb{C} d\pmb{m}^s
\end{equation}
and for $dX^{ss}$ we have,
\begin{equation}
dX^{ss} = \left( (\pmb{m}^{s})^T \left( \pmb{C} + \pmb{C}^T \right)\right) 
 d\pmb{m}^s     
\end{equation}

We can therefore write,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\pmb{f}^s}{\partial\pmb{m}^s} & =
-\sum_{s'\neq s} (X^{ss'})^{-2}
\pmb{m}^{s'} \left(\pmb{C} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \otimes \pmb{I}\right)
(\pmb{m}^{s'})^T \pmb{C}\nonumber \\
& - (X^{ss})^{-2}
\pmb{m}^{s} \left(\pmb{C} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \otimes \pmb{I}\right)
\left((\pmb{m}^s)^T (\pmb{C}+\pmb{C}^T) \right) \nonumber \\
& + (X^{ss})^{-1} \left(\pmb{C} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \otimes \pmb{I} \right)
\end{align}
or, alternatively,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\pmb{f}^s}{\partial\pmb{m}^s} & =
-\sum_{s'} (X^{ss'})^{-2}
\pmb{m}^{s'} \left(\pmb{C} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \otimes \pmb{I}\right)
(\pmb{m}^{s'})^T \pmb{C}\nonumber \\
& - (X^{ss})^{-2}
\pmb{m}^{s} \left(\pmb{C} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \otimes \pmb{I}\right)
(\pmb{C}\pmb{m}^s)^T   \nonumber \\
& + (X^{ss})^{-1} \left(\pmb{C} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \otimes \pmb{I} \right)
\end{align}
I would still prefer that we wrote this as
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\pmb{f}^s}{\partial\pmb{m}^s} & =
-\sum_{s'} (X^{ss'})^{-2}
 \left(\pmb{C} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \otimes \pmb{I}\right)
\pmb{m}^{s'}(\pmb{m}^{s'})^T \pmb{C}\nonumber \\
& - (X^{ss})^{-2}
 \left(\pmb{C} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \otimes \pmb{I}\right)
\pmb{m}^{s}(\pmb{C}\pmb{m}^s)^T   \nonumber \\
& + (X^{ss})^{-1} \left(\pmb{C} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \otimes \pmb{I} \right)
\end{align}

Since $\partial{\pmb{f}^s}/\partial{\pmb{m}^s}$ is a matrix, the r.h.s.
of this equation must also be a matrix. On the first line
we have the product of,
$$
\left(\pmb{C} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \otimes \pmb{I}\right)\pmb{m}^{s'} 
$$
which is a vector with,
$$
(\pmb{m}^{s'})^T\pmb{C}
$$
which is the transpose of a vector; the result is a matrix. On the second line we have the product of,
$$
 \left(\pmb{C} - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \otimes \pmb{I}\right)\pmb{m}^{s}
$$
which is a vector with,
$$
(\pmb{C}\pmb{m}^s)^T  
$$
which is the transpose of a vector; the result is a matrix. The third line is a matrix with the same dimensions.

Comment: There was a mistake in the differential of $X^{ss'}$ which I have corrected.

Comment: Hi Ted, so is the conclusion that my derivations are fine?

Comment: To be perfectly honest I find the notation you use a bit hard to follow. I can only vouch for what I have derived.